# How to simulate a mouse click in linux?

Tags: linux, wayland

How can I **simulate a mouse click under Linux**? (Cpp or Rust as a prefered Language for code)

I have been looking into possible solutions and have come across the following unsatisfactory ones:

- Use x11 lib -> I would prefer not to focus on x11 because I believe Wayland is the future and I don't want my program to depend on xwayland.
- Use /dev/uinput -> Requires root access, and I would like to be able to run my program without using sudo.
- Use xdotool or ydotool -> Same disadvantages as the previous two points respectively.

Is there another solution that **doesn't require x11 and sudo**?

Comment: We all love and cherish the current situation with X11 when any client can spoof input for any other client... NOT. If you want to spoof my input, you *better* be root.

Comment: You can take a look at the code for [wayvnc](https://github.com/any1/wayvnc/), a VNC server for Wayland. The [pointer.c](https://github.com/any1/wayvnc/blob/master/src/pointer.c) code seems to be what's used for mouse movement and mouse clicks.